# Property 'rotateZ' is not supported by native animated module

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated

I'm trying to include a rotation in my React Native animation. The object should rotate in a "2D way" around its center. In the standard CSS3 `transform` model, this would be a rotation about the Z axis.

```
style.transform = [{
    'rotateZ': animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0rad', targetAngle + 'rad']
    })
}]
```

This code works well, as long as I don't use `useNativeDriver = true`. So it seems that React Native indeed expects us to use `rotateZ` to rotate an item in a 2D way.

However, with `useNativeDriver = true`, I get an error:

```
Property 'rotateZ' is not supported by native animated module
```

How can I do this rotation with the native driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: I need to use `rotate` instead of `rotateZ`.

This seems strange, given that `rotateZ` works when not using `useNativeDriver = true`.

The full list of properties that are supported by the React Native native animation driver can be seen in the [`TRANSFORM_WHITELIST` constant](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js). In React Native 0.60, the following properties are supported:

```
translateX
translateY
scale
scaleX
scaleY
rotate
rotateX
rotateY
perspective
```

It seems the missing `rotateZ` [has since been added](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f4f08d3c549f2af7cd04ef78fe800d3bc12af1f0#diff-4d4bfac95b96bfe2f42b7eddd79418e1).

Comment: Check in the https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/66601e755fcad10698e61d20878d52194ad0e90c/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L185